# Switching USB mode - PTP or MTP

Tags: java, android

I'm new android programmer and I'm not able to find one thing. Is android application capable to switch between MTP and PTP modes (and to set it as default for the whole system)? If not how at least to run some system setting dialog giving to the user the possibility to switch between these two values. I've seen sth like this ex in Helium application. If the usb mode is incorrect, this app redirects user to the appropriate system setting dialog.

THanks in advance for help.